# Are these production rules for a formal grammar?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I have a question on if production rules of a formal grammar are being specified correctly.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) defines the syntax of grammars as the following finite set of production rules, where it states each rule has the form:

$(\Sigma \cup N)^{*}N(\Sigma \cup N)^{*} \implies (\Sigma \cup N)^{*}$

How can each rule have this form when each rule is a subset of the above arguments to the implication symbol?  Should quantification and the $\in$ symbol be used to specify each rule?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The use of notation in that statement might be confusing.  A grammar is a rule of the form "something $\to$ something", where the something on the left is a string of symbols containing at least one non-terminal symbol, and the something on the right is a string of symbols.

For instance, $A \to BcD$ would be a valid rule, as would $AB \to BDeeF$, or $aAcE \to b$.

If you read the very next sentence after the one you quoted, it explains the meaning of the part you didn't understand, in different words.  It says "That is, [...]" (you can read the rest yourself).  If you don't understand one sentence, in the future I suggest you keep reading a little further to see if you can work it out from context.